# Catalina import Library.xml into music app?

Tags: itunes, music

I have two itunes libraries. One is on Catalina and has a bunch of music. One is on Windows and has a bunch of different music. On the Windows machine I exported the Library xml file and copied the whole iTunes folder to my usb disk. I then went to the mac and opened the Library.xml file in a text editor and fixed up the paths to point to the correct location (e.g. `file:///Volumes/120GB SSD/iTunes/iTunes%20Media/Music/...`) and then when I go into Music and import the Library.xml file, nothing happens.... no feedback on screen, no error messages, no items appearing in my library. I had console up to look at the logs but not really sure what I am looking for and nothing notable appeared. Music doesn't seem to even try to deal with importing.

How can I copy my whole iTunes library from windows into my EXISTING mac library?

Comment: To import audio tracks it should be enough to drag the audio files into the main iTunes window and wait a while.

Comment: and what happens to all my playlists? And all the rating and playcount metadata of which the auto-playlists depend? That is what the library file is for, isn't it? Dragging audio files onto the app isn't the same thing.

Comment: That‘s right, but as far as I know iTunes doesn‘t support combining two libraries into one by importing the library file. Would actually be a good new question: how can I combine two iTunes libraries keeping all playcounts and playlists from both

Answer (score 1):

According to turingtest2 on Apple Support forums, you might be able to import the XML using the 'Import Playlist' function.

> The XML file is for third party support. The active iTunes library
> would normally have been called iTunes Library.itl though in some
> legacy systems the .itl extension might be omitted. You can hold down
> option while starting Music (or TV) and then use the Choose Library
> option to access an existing .itl file. You will be prompted for the
> path to store a new music (or TV) library converted from the old one.
> Alternatively you can use File > Library > Import Playlist... to
> import an XML file, but that will lose date added information that
> would be preserved by working with the .itl file. Either method should
> bring in ratings and playlists.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250869304